# GWT version with support of Java 1.8 and Dev mode debugging?

Tags: gwt, gwt-dev-mode

I have a requirement to use highest possible GWT version which support Dev mode debugging as well as Java 1.8

Comment: This question is pure laziness.
Anyway: http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html

Answer (score 0):

The latest version (2.8.1) still suports DevMode.

Comment: Latest version is 2.8.2 though.

Answer (score 0):

2.8.2 supports 1.8 and debugging in browser is well supported